# Tomar captura de un livestream en android

Tags: java, android, screenshot

Estoy haciendo una app que recibe video stream de una dirección RTSP y quiero tomar un screenshot de stream con solo tocar la pantalla... ya logré hacer que tome el screenshot pero el problema es que todos screenshot son imágenes en negro y en verdad necesito resolver esto.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            videoView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

            // Este es el código importante :)
            // Sin él la vista tendrá una dimensión de 0,0 y el mapa de bits será nula
            //btn.measure(VideoView.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, VideoView.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            //        VideoView.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, VideoView.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            //btn.layout(0, 0, videoView.getMeasuredWidth(), videoView.getMeasuredHeight());
            videoView.buildDrawingCache(true);
            videoView.invalidate();

            //videoView.buildDrawingCache(true);
            final Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(videoView.getDrawingCache());
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

            // Carpeta dónde guardamos la captura
            // En este caso, la raíz de la SD Card
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

            // El archivo que contendrá la captura
            File f = new File(sd, timeStamp+".JPEG");

            try {
                if (sd.canWrite()) {
                    f.createNewFile();
                    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
                    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, os);
                    os.close();
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            videoView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
            videoView.destroyDrawingCache();
        }
    });
```

Uso un button y un videoview ambos del tamaño de la pantalla y el button es transparente... quise hacerlo solo con el videoview pero no reacciona al evento onclicklistener